# why Status bar and Navigation bar background colors are different in ios

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I want to change background color of status bar and that background color should be same as navigation bar background color i.e dark gray color. My problem is after giving the same color for both status bar and navigation bar using my below code, i am getting the different color. I have already set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO. Please suggest me where i am doing wrong, i have attached below image for your reference.

[image]

here is my code of App delegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    //For changing status bar background color

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

    //For changing navigation bar background color

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

[image]

Comment: Is `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` same as `[UIColor darkGrayColor]`?

Comment: sry.. i am attaching the screenshot for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they have different colors is because `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` isn't the same color as `[UIColor darkGrayColor]`.

---

If it's fine to adjust navigation bar color after how the status bar looks like, then you can set the status bar color:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Find out the RGB values of the status bar. (For example, I use DigitalColor Meter, it says it has R:28, G: 28, B: 28).

Then you can do something like:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:28/255.0 green:28/255.0 blue:28/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
```

You might need to set translucency to `NO`.

If you only want it on certain screens, you can add this to the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:28/255.0 green:28/255.0 blue:28/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
```

Comment: Thanks @Lord Zsolt, i have done changes in my code. Now i am getting something like similar bg color for both. Can you please tell me if i need to set bg color as [UIColor colorWithRed:(51/255.0) green:(51/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:1.0]]; then what should be the bg and tint color for UINavigationBar?

Comment: That's what I said by "If it's fine to set the navigation bar color based on the status bar". The status bar has a few preset colors, you'll have to adjust navigation bar after that, not vice versa.

Comment: okey..now same background color are coming for my both Status bar and Navigation bar, but i dont know why i am getting one small black color separation line between Status bar and Navigation bar. pls check my updated question (i have attached the screenshot). pls suggest me..thanks

Comment: @YogeshSutharThanks for your answer..i have tried but its working only for black bg color not with any other color.

Comment: @AnandGautam Remove all your code for setting the statusBarBGColor and navigationcontroller BG color and then try my code. I have just checked with yellowColor and it is working properly.

Comment: @YogeshSutharOkey..please let me check in my code.And bar style should be UIBarStyleBlack? thanks alot

Comment: @AnandGautam Yes, otherwise the statusBar text color will be black.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56194/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-yogesh-suthar).

Answer (score 0):

First Change the statusBar style in your VC's viewDidLoad method

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

And then change the `BarTintColor` to your desired color in your VC's viewDidLoad method

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate`'s 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:' add following and it should work.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```